# dict comprehensions for mapping scrabble letter distribution

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list namely:

```
scrabble_scores = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
               (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
```

I have to write a function which gives a dict which contains a letter to score mapping whenever the above list is passed.please help me writing the function...!!

Comment: @Noctua yes in phyton

Comment: Smells like homework..

Comment: Hi, @user3226258, please note that people are likely to be more receptive to questions that show at least some effort on the part of the asker.

Comment: @thomasfedb I am a new to this forum so I am not clear next time i won't repeat this thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dict comprehension with two `for` loops to the rescue:

```
letter_score = {letter: score for score, letters in scrabble_scores
                              for letter in letters.split()}
```

E.g. for every letter in the string (separated by whitespace), produce a key and value pair in the output dictionary; the key is the letter, the value the score.

Demo:

```
>>> scrabble_scores = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
...                (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
>>> letter_score = {letter: score for score, letters in scrabble_scores
...                               for letter in letters.split()}
>>> letter_score
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 3, 'E': 1, 'D': 2, 'G': 2, 'F': 4, 'I': 1, 'H': 4, 'K': 5, 'J': 8, 'M': 3, 'L': 1, 'O': 1, 'N': 1, 'Q': 10, 'P': 3, 'S': 1, 'R': 1, 'U': 1, 'T': 1, 'W': 4, 'V': 4, 'Y': 4, 'X': 8, 'Z': 10}
>>> letter_score['Q']
10
```

Bonus word score calculator:

```
>>> word = 'QUICK'
>>> sum(letter_score[c] for c in word)
20
```

where `word` is a uppercase string containing only (scrabble) letters, ignoring double- and triple-letter scoring.

Answer (score 1):

Another, more verbose way:

```
def makeScoreDict(scrabble_scores):
        score_dict = {}
        for row in scrabble_scores:
            for letter in row[1].split():
                score_dict[letter] = row[0]
        return score_dict
```

Comment: Perfectly acceptable.

Comment: OP explicitly asked for dict comprehension in the question :p

Comment: Also, `str.split()` splits on whitespace by default. Why the explicit split on `" "`?

Comment: Good point. I pulled out `" "` from the `split()`.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can loop over pairs like this:

```
for score, letters in scrabble_scores:
    print("{}: {}".format(letters, score))
```

This will give as result:

```
"E A O I N R T L S U": 1
"D G": 2
...
```

In python, you can splits string containing spaces on those spaces:

```
>>> "E A O I N R T L S U".split()
['E', 'A', 'O', 'I', 'N', 'R', 'T', 'L', 'S', 'U']
```

Now just combine the two:

```
for score, letters in scrabble_scores:
    for letter in letters.split():
        # voila, you've got score and letter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Seems to be what you describe.

```
scrabble_scores = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
               (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]
out_dict = {} 
for score in scrabble_scores:
    val = score[0]
    for letter in score[1].split():
        out_dict[letter] = val
print out_dict
```

Comment: OP explicitly asked for dict comprehension in the question :p

Comment: While i agree with you, it would also seem that he might have meant how to comprehend how dict's work. as you would not write a function for dict comprehension. :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-dict comprehension answer.

```
scrabble_scores = [(1, "E A O I N R T L S U"), (2, "D G"), (3, "B C M P"),
           (4, "F H V W Y"), (5, "K"), (8, "J X"), (10, "Q Z")]

d = dict()
for value,letters in scrabble_scores:
    d.update(dict(zip(letters.split(),[value]*len(letters.split())))
```

I would definitely do this as a dict comp as well, and I'm sure that's what OP is going for, but `dict(zip(iter,iter))` is a useful expression worth mentioning.